# How to start a page with web view in the Xcode?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uiwebview

I see here that many using this code but do working with me. Well. (DESKTOP APP)

Simple webview auto laucher URL

I will go to talk step by step

1) Create a project

2) Create a window and a web view

3) Put the identifier how prevelwindow (web view) and windows (window)

4) In My .H

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSWindow *window;
WebView *prevelwindow;
}

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) IBOutlet WebView *prevelwindow;
@end
```

5) In My .M

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@synthesize prevelwindow;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com.br";

[[prevelwindow mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL             URLWithString:urlString]]];
}

@end
```

6) Well then I compile it and it is not working.

Comment: What errors are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: Also, I have an open source app you can download for reference. https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/basic-web-browser

Comment: Try creating a new Project with my instructions (See my answer below). Might be something wrong with your current project.

Comment: ...ok.. the error is : No known class method for selector 'mainFrame'

Comment: I downloaded your project josiah, but i need that my App open and start a website automatic, without bars, just web view

Answer (score 1):

First off you must add the [image: WebKit.framework] (`Targets->Build Phases->Link Binary`).

Then you can `#import` it in your `.h AppDelegate` file and declare a new `WebView`:

```
#import "WebKit/WebKit.h"

@interface Check_AccountzAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    WebView *MyWebView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *MyWebView;
```

Now you can load a new Request (`.m AppDelegate` file):

```
@synthesize MyWebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [[MyWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

And finally add a WebView, and connect it to your `MyWebView` `IBOutlet` in your `.nib` file:

New `WebView`:
[image: Add a new WebView]

Connect the `IBOutlet`:
[image: Outlets][image: TheWebObj]

Comment: Error :( No known class method for selector 'mainFrame'

Comment: Thanks for all, i download project opensource from josiah e all right!! thanks!!